# host not found error in host names with ip's side by side in ipscanner

Tags: python, sockets

This code is saying that host not found but there are some hosts in that ip range? error is at socket.gethostbyaddr(ip) but i don't know why because it is the command to find hostnames by ip address?

```
import subprocess
import socket
import os
with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
        for n in xrange(10, 240):
                ip="10.4.16.{0}".format(n)
                result=subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", ip],
                        stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait()
                if result:
                        print (ip, "inactive")
                else:
                        print (ip, "active", socket.gethostbyaddr(ip))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before everything, your IP address must have a ptr record in DNS that show it names.otherwise, you with this code you can check is

active or not

```
import subprocess
import socket
import os
import sys

def lookup(addr):
     try:
         return socket.gethostbyaddr(addr)
     except socket.herror:
         return None, None, None  
with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
    for n in xrange(10, 240):
        ip="10.4.16.{0}".format(n)
        if sys.platform=="linux" or sys.platform=="darwin":
            result=os.system("ping -c 1 -t 1 " + ip+ " > /dev/null 2>&1")
        else:
            result=os.system("ping -w 1000 -n 1 " + ip)

        if result==0:
            print (ip, "active")
            name,alias,addresslist = lookup(ip)
            if name != None:
                print ("name", name)
        else:
            print (ip, "inactive")
        print "#################################"
```

Comment: i tried it but it is giving output more than host names can you suggest something for getting only hostname

Comment: after 10.4.16.137 it is giving me error as socket.herror host not found

Comment: if you just want name you can print only name of host like this `print (ip, "active", socket.gethostbyaddr(ip))[0]` . its because only before 137 are active and other hosts are not active

Comment: your hosts probably don't have ptr record and you can't see their names, I changed your code that can detect active host and if they have ptr record you can see their name also and if not you can see that they are active

Comment: this new code output some non active ip's showing as  active and that only host name is working fine thanks again

Comment: is it right to use if not there if i removed not it is working fine

Comment: your ping function does not work correctly, it suppose all hosts is active,I am fixing it

Comment: ping is now fixed,you can check it out

Comment: it's saying that system cannot find the path specified. I am using Windows 7 system

Comment: ok, I changed it to work with multi-platform.unfortunately you can't ignore the output of ping in windows platform with os.system if it bothering you, you have to install another library

Comment: you can check answer as correct, it's below the down vote icon

Comment: do you know how to print this output to tkinter gui?

Comment: unfortunately i didn't use it so far

Comment: ok boss thank you once again for giving your valuable time for my doubts

Comment: can you explain with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo in the code why are we using limbo whenever we try to do ping.exactly what is limbo

Comment: @RamaKrishnaPolumuru I suggest you to create new question as in comments its not a good place to discuss too long